# Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and two AuthenticationProviders

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have two `AuthenticationProviders` and don't know how to translate this to the new way of Spring Security.
This is what I mean by "the new way" https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Currently I'm extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and have this configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(inMemoryAuthenticationProvider);
    auth.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

How must the configuration look like without extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Comment: The new way you referring is on 6.0.0?

Comment: @pringi https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Comment: Probably you can declare two beans (using @Order), return respectively InMemoryAuthenticationProvider and LdapAuthenticationProvider. Declare another bean returning your UserDetailsService. This should be the same as your current configuration. Example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/5.7.x/servlet/java-configuration/hello-security/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/5.7.x/servlet/java-configuration/authentication/username-password/ldap/src/main/java/example/SecurityConfiguration.java

Comment: But the two are implemeting AuthenticationProvider and are already beans. Same for the UserDetailsService. I don't understand how Spring wires these togheter without the AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by using filterChain as @Elyobek sugested but with this code:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authenticationProvider(inMemoryAuthenticationProvider);
    http.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);
    http.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}
```

I didn't realize that I can set the `AuthenticationProviders` and `UserDetailsService` on `HttpSecurity`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig {

        private AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder;

        public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder) {
            this.authBuilder = authBuilder;
        }

        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            authBuilder.authenticationProvider(inMemoryAuthenticationProvider);
            authBuilder.authenticationProvider(ldapAuthenticationProvider);
            authBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

            http
                    .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    )
                    .authenticationManager(authBuilder.getOrBuild())
                   .httpBasic(withDefaults());
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```